# Output data to CSV specific columns from Dictionary c#

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to output the values from the dictionary to the CSV and am able to do this. But facing issue with the specific columns this need to output to the csv. I need the specific data value from dictionary to be output to a specific column in csv.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> file = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

for (var i = 0; i < stringList.Count(); i++)
{
    string line = stringList[i];
    string path = line.Replace("\r\n", "");
    path = path.Replace(" ", "");
    path = path.TrimEnd(':');

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        file[path] = file.ContainsKey(path) ? file[path] : new List<string>();
        for (var j = i + 1; j < stringList.Count(); j++)
        {
            string line2 = stringList[j];
            string path2 = line2.Replace("\r\n", "");
            path2 = path2.Replace(" ", "");
            path2 = path2.TrimEnd(':');

            if (File.Exists(path2))
            {
                i = j - 1;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (path2.Contains("Verified") | path2.Contains("Algorithm"))
                {
                    var strings = path2.Split(':');
                    var listValue = strings[1].Trim();
                    file[path].Add(listValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}                

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(outputdir + "\\output_" + 
        DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HHmmss") + ".csv"))
{
    writer.WriteLine("FilePath,Signature,HashValueSHA1, HashValueSHA2, HashValueMD5, Other");
    foreach (var keyvaluepair in file)
    {
        if (!keyvaluepair.Value.Contains("Unsigned"))
        {
            var values = String.Join(",", keyvaluepair.Value.Distinct().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
            writer.WriteLine("{0},{1}", keyvaluepair.Key, values);
        }
    }
}
```

Current Output looks like below:

[image: Current CSV Output with my code above]

Sample output I need as below:

[image: CSV Output]

The Dictionary key(string) would hold the file path and the values(List) would hold something like below:

Signed
sha1RSA
md5RSA
md5RSA

Signed
sha1RSA
sha1RSA
sha256RSA
sha256RSA

Please suggest how can I get the one as required output.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the definition of the dictionary (e.g. is it a `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>`) and how the information is organized within it?

Comment: @JohnWu Hi John, I just included my additional code

Comment: If possible, can you also post what is present in stringList?

Comment: @kamalpreet: Please find the updated the post

Comment: It'd help if you can add at least 2,3 rows which will show how the N/A are present

Comment: `dictionaryfile` isn't declared anywhere, and it looks like that's the important part.

Comment: @ScottHannen: Sorry I just updated the code above

Comment: Hi @kamalpreet, Please find that would be my question above on how to get N/A added to the output in specific columns so that I can have a uniformity. The current output is messed up with string values just joining what is in the List in dictionary.

Comment: Got it. Where does `stringList` come from? Is it something you formed yourself or you read it from some source?

Comment: @kamalpreet: I am running a tool to get the details. I do initiate a process for running the tool and assign the output to a string and then split it line by line. Sample code: string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var stringList = content.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a longer answer typed, but I see the problem.

On this line

```
var values = String.Join(",", keyvaluepair.Value.Distinct().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

take out `Distinct`. It looks like you have the correct number of items in each string, but if a list contains multiple blank entries `Distinct` is eliminating the duplicates. If a list contains two or three blank entries you need all of them. If you delete duplicate blanks your columns won't line up.

Also, when you use `Distinct` there's no guarantee that items will come back in any particular order. In this case the order is very important so that values end up in the right columns.

So in your example above, even though there's a blank in the third column of the first row, the value from the fourth column ends up in the third column and the blank goes to the end.

---

That will likely fix the immediate problem. I'd recommend not using a `List<string>` when you're expecting a certain number of values (they need to match up with columns) because a `List<string>` can contain any number of values.

Instead, try something like this:

```
public class WhateverThisIs
{
    public string Signature { get; set; }
    public string HashValueSha1 { get; set; }
    public string HashValueSha2 { get; set; }
    public string HashValueMd5 { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

Then, as a starting point, use `Dictionary<string, WhateverThisIs>`.

Then the part that outputs lines would look more like this:

```
var value = keyvaluepair.Value;
var values = String.Join(",", value.Signature, value.HashValueSha1, value.HashValueSha2,
    value.HashValueMd5, value.Other);
```

(and yes, that accounts for null values.)

If you want to replace nulls or empty values with "N/A" then you'd need a separate function for that, like

```
string ReplaceNullWithNa(string value)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? "N/A" : value;
}
```

Comment: Wow Scott Hannen :-).. Thank you so much for your input. I will try with this method and hopefully this should fix my problem.

Comment: This fixed my problem :-)